# qTip2 with AJAX tooltips not working

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I've suddenly got a problem using qTip2 and AJAX. The site was working fine until a few days ago and now the tooltips aren't working.

Here's the draft page I'm working on:
http://trenthergenrader.com/calypsis/experimental/frame2.html

The page is split into two unequally sized frames. The one on the left is a story that has links to the work's wiki of people, places, and things. When you click on a link, the tooltip is supposed to fire and display a mini description and thumbnail of the wiki item, along with a link to the full wiki entry. The user can either close the tooltip and continue reading or click on the link and leave the narrative frame page and go to the wiki. However, what's happening now is the link goes straight to the wiki entry with no tooltip.

Here's the page for the frame with the page using tooltips:
http://trenthergenrader.com/calypsis/experimental/Untitled-2.html

There is quite possibly some boneheaded coding error I'm not seeing because I don't really know what I'm doing with jquery. Can someone with more experience/knowledge give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, have you tried using an earlier version of jQuery. I had an issue a while back regarding this plugin that using an older version of jQ fixed, although, I cannot remember all the details, sadly.

Comment: I changed the jquery version to 1.7.2 and that seemed to fix the problem. Just hope it doesn't break again... Thanks though!